# How to write this SQL query as per requirement

Tags: sql, database, dml

Consider the following schema of a company database (primary keys are in bold).

```
Employee (**EmployeeID**, Name, Office, Email, Sex, Salary, DepartmentID)
Department (**DepartmentID**, DepartmentName)
Project (**ProjectID**, DepartmentID, Duration)
EmployeeProject (**EmployeeID, ProjectID**, WorkHours)
```

Find the proejct whose total work hours is the second longest, with SINGLE QUERY statement. **Try not use top or limit.**

Below is my solution, its rather ugly and inefficient.

```
select projectid
from (
    select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
    from employeeproject ep
    group by projectid
) sum
where hours = (
    select max(hours)
    from (
        select projectid, hours
        from (
            select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
            from employeeproject ep
            group by projectid
        ) sum
        where hours < (
            select max(hours)
            from (
                select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
                from employeeproject ep
                group by projectid
            ) sum
        )
    ) sec
)
```

Comment: What solution have you already tried that didn't work?

Comment: It seems to be like some assignment or interview question...

Comment: Formatting the question doesn't actually help it.

Comment: Yes, it is an exam question, but ok to ask right? or not?

Comment: Ok to ask...ok with psuedo answer?   I try to avoid the where in () logic and prefer joining subqueries instead.  Create a max query that gets the sum of hours by projectID...left join this to a subquery that selects the maximum hours value.  Have a where clause to filter out where the subquery is null (effectively filters out the longest project)...select max from that to get second longest.  It's a few nested subqueries, but I'd go that route before the where in / where not in route

Comment: select sum3.projectid
from (
 select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
 from employeeproject ep
 group by projectid
) sum3
where hours = (
 select max(hours)
 from (
  select sum1.projectid, sum1.hours
  from (
   select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
   from employeeproject ep
   group by projectid
  ) sum1,
  (
   select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
   from employeeproject ep
   group by projectid
  ) sum2
  where sum1.hours < sum2.hours
 ) sec
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a homework question, full answers are out as per the site policy:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812

However, it looks like we are allowed to point you in the right direction. :)

Try breaking the problem down into steps:

1. **Find the total work hours for each project** - you've already done that.
2. **Find the two longest projects** - look at the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` operators.
3. **Find the shortest of those two projects** - `ORDER BY` can work in ascending or descending order.

It should then be fairly obvious how to combine those steps into a single query.

Comment: select projectid
from (
 select projectid, sum(workhours) as hours
 from employeeproject ep
 group by projectid
 order by sum(workhours) desc
 limit 2
) sum
order by hours
limit 1

Comment: I guess this is what you mean, it works with my test data. Somehow top or limit is not taught at all, so I think that is not the expecting answer.

Comment: @David: I guess it depends on whether your teacher will only accept a specific answer, or will accept any answer that solves the problem as stated. :)

Comment: Yes, I think I need to clarify this accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

select ProjectID
from EmployeeProject
where WORKHOURS = (select MAX(WORKHOURS) 
                    FROM EmployeeProject
                    WHERE WORKHOURS < ( 
                                          SELECT MAX(WORKHOURS) FROM EmployeeProject
                                          )
                                )